# Ajax not working in CefSharp based WebView with local files

Tags: ajax, webview, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have successfully embedded CefSharp in win form application using VS-2008 i am loading a jQueryMobile based webpage in webView which uses #id based ajax calls. which are not working in webView. 
Is there any way to disable the security so i can load local files in the webview ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the answer by my self just needed a single line to do it

```
_browserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed = true;
```