# How to execute local files on embedded chrome using Awesomium.NET or CefSharp

Tags: owin, awesomium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have used several solutions like Berkelium project, CEfSharp, awesomium.net, The Web application i built constitutes of Javascipts, xml, CSS. When I used these solutions for files published on server they properly work out but when i give path like (file:///path) it stops responding.

Comment: What errors show in Developer Tools console?

Comment: It dose not show any error, Only Blank page appears. I did used "allow file access for files" command in CMD for my HTML but still same result

Comment: Check for errors in debug.log file, set appropriate errror reporting. Implement CefLoadHandler::OnLoadError and see the error code.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs as alternatives to `file://` maybe look at either:

- Implementing a [SchemeHandler](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/CefSharpSchemeHandler.cs) as showcased by both the CefSharp.WinForms.Example and WPF ditto.
- Maybe even an OWIN married with CEF implementation, like [Harley](https://github.com/eVisionSoftware/Harley#harley-)
- or see this other answer: [Ajax not working in CefSharp based WebView with local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291510/ajax-not-working-in-cefsharp-based-webview-with-local-files)